# Facebook Comment not loading on view change with Angular JS + Jquery conflict

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I integrated angular in my project which has got two views. There is facebook comment associated with `view1`, so that it won't show up in `view2`.

When I'm loading view1 for the first time, facebook comment is loading and showing up. Then surprisingly, after clicking the anchor tag to go to `view2` and returning back to `view1`, the facebook comment is not loading or showing up.

I tried putting facebook comment for `view2` also. But it's not showing when I go to `view2`. Does it have anything to do with `window.load function?` This is just one of the issues. None of the `javascripts` apart from this are working also after coming back to this view or going to another view. But they are working on page load for the first time. Strange

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/app/controller/baseController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/app/controller/aboutController.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
(function(angular){ 
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    // Routes
    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'BaseController',
            templateUrl: 'assets/app/views/base.html'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            controller: 'AboutController',
            templateUrl: 'assets/app/views/about.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
})(window.angular);
```

View 1 controller

```
(function(angular){
    var app = angular.module('myApp');
    var BaseController = function($scope){
        function fbLoad(){
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=xxxxx";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        }
        fbLoad();
    };

    BaseController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    app.controller('BaseController', BaseController);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: @Danscho No errors. 0 errors. Check the answer. I edited it. I initialized my module in another file and was referencing it in the controller.

Comment: Already deleted my comment after I reread your question.